# is there have a way to delay my stylesheets a bit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Is there have a way to delay my stylesheets a bit, If there have what will be the best way or the efficient way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- UTF-8 -->
    <!-- viewport -->
    <!-- icon -->
    <!-- title -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_4.css">


    <!-- 1000 milliseconds style_1.css -->
    <!-- 2000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 3000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 4000 milliseconds style_2.css -->
    <!-- 5000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 6000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 7000 milliseconds style_3.css -->
    <!-- 8000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 9000 milliseconds -->
    <!-- 10000 milliseconds style_4.css -->

</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

In the index.html page, I have to load(sends to new visitor's cache) and I want to delay "style_2.css", "style_3.css" and "style_4.css". Because once a new visitor goes to another page, that page will load instantly

Comment: No there isn't, but this sounds like an X/Y question. Delaying loading a stylesheet is not something you should really be doing, and sounds like your attempt at a solution when there are far better approaches. Can you please edit the question to give a clear description of your goal.

Comment: The thing is, only the first stylesheet is needed for the index.html page. but I want to push other stylesheets to the cache. the reason is when new visitors go to other pages it will load soon. I'm doing to optimize the overall speed

Comment: In that case I think you're worrying about something that is not an issue. CSS files will be cached after the first load, so subsequent loads will be instant. Only the first load will have any performance hit, and if your CSS is causing a noticeable performance penalty then the issue is that you need to reduce and optimise your CSS file(s), not band-aid a fix with some odd method of caching.

Answer (score 1):

It is **NOT Recommended** to manualy delay loading your resources,

...but you could always use

```js
setTimeout(() => {

    //Do stuff, in your case add a style to the document
    document.body.innerHTML += `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_1.css">`;
    

    //wait for 500 miliseconds then do the above ^
}, 500);
```

Keep in mind this is still a vary dirty way of doing stuff, but judging from what you are asking in the first place, I don't think you really care about your code being all that clean :)

Comment: The thing is, only the first stylesheet is needed for the index.html page. but I want to push other stylesheets to the cache. the reason is when new visitors go to other pages it will load soon. I'm doing to optimize the overall speed